# Different sample size of control and test groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample, control-group, feature-weighting

Hope someone can help my question:

I have a survey study with one control group and one test group. Each is set to have 500 completes. However, we are short in sample in one group: Test is 350 and Control is 500.

Question 1: Do I need to apply weighting to the total sample size of the Test group in order to do the data analysis against the Control group? If yes, how should I do it?

Question 2: How many more completes should I get for the Test Group in order to compare to the Control Group with 500 completes? I am sure that i cannot get all 500 completes for the Test Group.

Thank you in advance,

Cathy

Comment: You did not say what analysis you would perform. But do not need to have equal sample sizes in two groups generally. 350 vs 500 is OK.

Comment: Suppose this is a paired design. For example 500 students and tests before and after instruction for each student. Then only the data where you have both pre and post tests are useful. So you'd use 350 pairs. // Suppose this is a 2-sample design intended to compare 500 subjects from Population A and 500 from Pop B, but you got 500 from A and 350 from B. If you really think both samples are truly representative of their populations, then it's OK to run a 2-sample test on the 'unbalanced' data. However, if the reason for having only 350 from B affects data values for B, then you have trouble.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me user158565 and BruceET. The analysis is about ad perception at the specific locations with and without ad screens. I need to compare two groups. There are no quotas in each group in terms of age and gender. So I have a group of 350 completes which their locations have an ad screen vs a group of 500 completes which don't have an ad screen. I want to know if it is statistically valid to compare 2 groups? Does weighting need to apply to the first group? If yes, how? Thank you!